# Android Chrome: 500KB Image Upload, Image Tag Preview Error

Tags: javascript, android, typescript

When uploading images (500KB or less) to a web app using the input tag on Android, and creating Base64 or Blob using createObjectURL or FileReader, I encounter image errors when applying the image to the src attribute of the  tag. How can I resolve this issue?

using blob, base64 ...

Comment: Can you provide some code snippets?

Comment: @stratov

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL 

I tested it as per the code provided in the link above.

After entering Chrome on Android, I uploaded a self-taken photo that is below 500KB, but an error occurred in the preview.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.